# confusing about double quoting

Tags: shell, find, quoting, wildcards

I learned when I use command, double quoting treat all things as character except $, `, \ .

But, when use command like `find -type f -name "*.jpg"` `*.jpg` is inside double quotes. Then, it means we want to treat `*` and `.` as just a character. So, the `find` command should output regular file which has name `*.jpg` as it says, not pathname expansion implemented.

If we want to do pathname expansion, I think I have to do type command `find -type f -name *.jpg`(without double quoting).

But, the result is same. Why use double quoting in this command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a subtlety to how wildcard expansion works. Change to a directory which contains no .jpg files and type

```
echo *.jpg
```

and it will output

```
*.jpg
```

In particular, the string *.jpg is left unmodified. If, however, you change to a directory containing .jpg files, for example suppose we have two files: image1.jpg and image2.jpg, then the echo *.jpg command will not output

```
image1.jpg image2.jpg
```

and the *.jpg gets expanded.

If you type

```
find . -name *.jpg
```

and there are no .jpg files in the directory you are when you type this, then find will receive the arguments ".", "-name" and "*.jpg". If, however, you type this command in a directory containing .jpg files, say image1.jpg and image2.jpg, then find will receive the arguments ".", "-name", "image1.jpg" and "image2.jpg", so will in effect run the command

```
find . -name image1.jpg image2.jpg
```

and find will complain. What can be really confusing if you omit the quotes is if there is a single .jpg file (say image1.jpg). Then the wildcard expansion will result in

```
find . -name image1.jpg
```

and the find command will find all files whose basename is image1.jpg.

Aside: This does lead to a useful bash idiom for seeing if any files match a given pattern:

```
if [ "$(echo *.jpg)" = "*.jpg" ]; then
    # *.jpg has no matches
else
    # *.jpg has matches
fi
```

though be warned that this will not work if there is a file called '*.jpg' in the current directory. To be more watertight, you can do

```
if [ "$(echo *.jpg)" = "*.jpg" ] && [ ! -e "*.jpg" ]; then
    # *.jpg has no matches
else
    # *.jpg has matches
fi
```

(While not directly relevant to the the question, I added this since it illustrates some of the aspects of how wildcard expansion works.)

Comment: That `bash` idiom is somewhat horrifying.

Comment: The rest of the answer is good info but doesn't fully answer the question; [PSkocik's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264399/135943) does.  The point that `find` does pattern matching, not glob expansion, is the key.  So you need to *prevent* your shell from doing glob expansion so `find` receives the pattern you intend.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the asterisk in the name pattern because `find` wants to do its own glob expansion in all the various directories it searches. If left unescaped, the `*` would get expanded by the shell, and for the current directory only. That would likely yield an illegal `find` invocation.

Comment: So, if I use double quotes outside of name pattern, then `find` command internally expands double quoted strings? (I mean just send double quoted string to `find` command, and `find` command does its own expansion?)

Comment: Quotes are a shell thing. They don't get passed to the invoked program/function/script. When you do `cmd '*.jpg'` then `*.jpg` gets passed. If you don't quote it, shell will expand it and instead of `*.jpg`  the expanded list of files will get passed.

Comment: PSkocik - maybe a better word would be "escape"... `find . -name \*.jpg` or `find . -name '*.jpg'` work equally well. The idea here is that `find` does pattern matching not expansion.

Comment: @don_crissti +1 good  point, fixed it.

Comment: Can I understand then, in pattern matching, `find` command also use wildcard(which is passed through double-quoted string)?